# solve an equation with e raised to two different exponents

Tags: calculus

Can you help me understand how to solve an exponential equation with e raised to two different exponents?  Here is an example of the type of problem I am trying to solve.
$600e^{-.02x}=200-200e^{-.04x}$

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint: if you write $y=e^{-0.02x}$, then $y^2 = e^{-0.04x}$. Do you see how that might be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
600e^{-0.02x} & =200-200\Big(e^{-0.02x}\Big)^2 \\[10pt]
600 u & = 200 - 200u^2
\end{align}
where $u=e^{-0.02x}$.  Finding $u$ is solving a quadratic equation.  (I'd divide both sides by $200$ first.)

Once you've got $u$, think about finding $x$.